# How to shift overlaying lines that are created with pstricks?

Tags: math-mode, nodes, decorations, node-connections

I am using `pstricks` to connect entries of 4x4-matrices with lines, more precisely, I use `\ncline{}{}`to connect two elements of a given matrix, that I initiated with `\Rnode{}{}.`

I iniated a 4x4-matrix with entries 1 to 16, I want to connect 1 and 6, as well as 1 and 11, but the line between 1 and 11 overlays the line between 1 and 6, such that only the line between 1 and 11 appears on the output.

```
\begin{pspicture}
\begin{pmatrix}
\Rnode{1}{1} & \Rnode{2}{2} & \Rnode{3}{3} & \Rnode{4}{4} \\ 
\Rnode{5}{5} & \Rnode{6}{6} & \Rnode{7}{7} & \Rnode{8}{8} \\ 
\Rnode{9}{9} & \Rnode{10}{10} & \Rnode{11}{11} & \Rnode{12}{12} \\ 
\Rnode{13}{13} & \Rnode{14}{14} & \Rnode{15}{15} & \Rnode{16}{16}
\end{pmatrix} 
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, nodesep=0.5pt}
\ncline{1}{6} \ncline{1}{11}
\end{pspicture}
```

[image: Picture of the matrix with the overlaying lines]

How can I shift one of the lines, such that two lines are visible? How can I manage the case, if three lines are overlaying in this manner?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are: you have to use the `offset =` key. I would do it with 3 lines, personally:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, array}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{pspicture}
\begin{pmatrix}
\Rnode{1}{1} & \Rnode{2}{2} & \Rnode{3}{3} & \Rnode{4}{4} \\
\Rnode{5}{5} & \Rnode{6}{6} & \Rnode{7}{7} & \Rnode{8}{8} \\
\Rnode{9}{9} & \Rnode{10}{10} & \Rnode{11}{11} & \Rnode{12}{12} \\
\Rnode{13}{13} & \Rnode{14}{14} & \Rnode{15}{15} & \Rnode{16}{16}
\end{pmatrix}
\psset{linewidth=0.4pt}
\ncline{1}{6}\ncline{6}{11}
\psset{nodesep=0.5pt, offset = 2.5pt}
\ncline{6}{1}
\psset{nodesepA =-1.5pt}
\ncline{1}{6}
\psset{nodesepB =-1pt}
 \ncline{6}{11}\ncline{11}{16}
\end{pspicture} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this way I coud still not draw three lines from 1 to 6,11 and 16 (at least I don't see how). Do you know a solution?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is it closer to what you want?

Comment: Thanks again, but I interpret your updated picture now as one line connecting 1 and 6 plus a second line connecting 1 and 16. The third line, connecting 1 and 11 is missing. In the area between 1 and 6, there would have to be 3 parallel lines.

Comment: I think I've finally understood. Please see the second update.