# How to shift parallel lines, drawn into a matrix with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, amsmath, tikz-styles, decorations

I am initiating a 4x4-matrix and want to connect several entries with lines using TikZ. Now the problem is, that some parallel lines might overlap, as seen in the following example:

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcommand\tikznode[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};}}


    $
    \begin{pmatrix} \tikznode{1}{1} &  \tikznode{2}{2} & \tikznode{3}{3} & \tikznode{4}{4} \\
    \tikznode{5}{5} &\tikznode{6}{6} &\tikznode{7}{7} &\tikznode{8}{8} \\
    \tikznode{9}{9} & \tikznode{10}{10} &\tikznode{11}{11} &\tikznode{12}{12} \\
    \tikznode{13}{13} &\tikznode{14}{14} &\tikznode{15}{15} &\tikznode{16}{16} \end{pmatrix}
    $
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[-](1)--(6);\draw[-](1)--(11);(1)--(16);}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Overlapping lines in matrix]

I am looking for a way, to draw three lines, connecting 1 respectively with 6,11 and 16, into one matrix, parallely shifted against each other, such that all of them are visible.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: If you want to consider doing this with `pstricks` you can take a look at my  answer to the similar question on [overlaying lines in matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413406/how-to-shift-overlaying-lines-that-are-created-with-pstricks).

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it using `tikz`, because using `pstricks` the compilation of the file always takes very long

Comment: It's longer the first time because it has to delocalise the making of the graphic file. Once it's OK, you can ise the `[off]` option of auto-pst-pdf to not regenerate this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcommand\tikznode[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.center)]{\node(#1)[inner sep=1pt,fill=white]{#2};}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
    $
    \begin{pmatrix} \tikznode{1}{1} &  \tikznode{2}{2} & \tikznode{3}{3} & \tikznode{4}{4} \\
    \tikznode{5}{5} &\tikznode{6}{6} &\tikznode{7}{7} &\tikznode{8}{8} \\
    \tikznode{9}{9} & \tikznode{10}{10} &\tikznode{11}{11} &\tikznode{12}{12} \\
    \tikznode{13}{13} &\tikznode{14}{14} &\tikznode{15}{15} &\tikznode{16}{16} \end{pmatrix}
    $
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw(1.10)--(6.125);
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[red](1)--(11);
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[blue](1.-60)--(16.170);
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this protocol: (name.10).  Where in the manual is this described?

Comment: @JohnKormylo See pp.134-136, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a.

Comment: (name.north) is a shortcut for (name.90) and (name.north west) is a shortcut for (name.135). Some node shape have connecting points as p. 695 of the manual.

Comment: This is a good answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

A simpler all-tikz approach using the `matrix` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
  \usepackage{amsmath}

  \begin{document}
  \[%
    \begin{pmatrix}\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes, column sep=1em] {
    1 & 2  & 3  & 4  \\
    5 & 6  & 7  & 8  \\
    9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
    13& 14 & 15 & 16 \\};
    \path[->](m-1-1) edge[bend left =00] (m-2-2)
                     edge[bend left =20] (m-3-3)
                     edge[bend right=20] (m-4-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}\end{pmatrix}
  \]

\end{document}
```

[image]